# Does Round() Function works differently inside trigger?

Tags: mysql, triggers

I am working on a educational project where I have to create an eshop. I am using mysql to build my database. I have 3 tables A."books" B."users" C."REVIEWS". REVIEWS table have `id` as primary key, `user_id` as foreign key, and `book_id` as foreign key, a column called `comments` that keeps user's comments and the column rating that keep user rating for the a book. In books table I have a field called total_rating that keeps the total rating of reviews for the book.
I want to create a trigger that updates the  total rating and the number of ratings(column in books table) after insert on reviews table.

```
CREATE TABLE `books` (
  `id` int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `title` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `ISBN` char(13) NOT NULL,
  `No_of_pages` varchar(6) NOT NULL,
  `description` text,
  `regular_price` decimal(5,2) NOT NULL,
  `store_quantity` int DEFAULT NULL,
  `image` blob,
  `total_rating` decimal(2,1) DEFAULT NULL,
  `count_reviews` int DEFAULT NULL,
  `count_sales` int DEFAULT NULL,
  `author_id` int DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `books_author_id_authors_id_fk` (`author_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `books_author_id_authors_id_fk` FOREIGN KEY (`author_id`) REFERENCES `authors` (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=7 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci;
```

```
CREATE TABLE `reviews` (
  `id` int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `user_id` int NOT NULL,
  `book_id` int NOT NULL,
  `rating` decimal(2,1) DEFAULT NULL,
  `review_datetime` datetime NOT NULL,
  `comment` varchar(400) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `combined_user_book` (`user_id`,`book_id`),
  KEY `reviews_user_id_users_id_fk_idx` (`user_id`),
  KEY `reviews_book_id_books_id_fk_idx` (`book_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `reviews_book_id_books_id_fk` FOREIGN KEY (`book_id`) REFERENCES `books` (`id`),
  CONSTRAINT `reviews_user_id_users_id_fk` FOREIGN KEY (`user_id`) REFERENCES `users` (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=6 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci;
```

So I've made this trigger

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE TRIGGER tr_insert_reviews
AFTER INSERT
ON `reviews` FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
DECLARE bookid int;
DECLARE lastid int;
DECLARE aveg int;
DECLARE reviews_number int;
SELECT id FROM reviews ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1 into lastid; 
SELECT book_id FROM reviews WHERE id = lastid into bookid;
SELECT ROUND(AVG(rating),1) FROM reviews WHERE book_id = bookid into aveg;
SELECT COUNT(rating) FROM reviews WHERE book_id = bookid into reviews_number;
UPDATE books SET total_rating = aveg, count_reviews = reviews_number WHERE id = bookid;
END //
DELIMITER ;
```

Trigger works, but doesn't keep the exact decimal to the result but rounds the decimal to zero.For example instead of giving 3.9 which is the real result, rounds it to 4.0.When I do it outside the trigger it keeps the decimal normally. Do you have any idea how I could solve this?
Plus, I am not sure if it'a agood idea to create a trigger to calculate the total_rating automatically after insert in reviews table.I thought that it would be better, in order not to make this proccess on back end(java rest api project).What do you think?
Last but not least, is there anyway to tell a trigger to run after or before delete/update and get the id of the deleted/updated row?

Sorry for the multiple questions,I am really new in programming and questions are increased  exponentially in my head.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: `DECLARE aveg int;` is the answer to your question.

Comment: Thank you so much, I should have noticed!